# Linux TC / Policy Routing tools

Tags: linux, routing, qos, traffic-shaping

In addition to a really good firewall Linux has a builtin advanced routing and traffic shaping ([lartc](http://lartc.org/howto/)).

There are many applications ([firehol](http://firehol.sourceforge.net/), [firestarter](http://www.fs-security.com/), etc) to make the creation of iptables firewall easier, what similar to tools exist to make working with the policy routing and traffic control easy?

Answer (score 1):

I think [wondershaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/) is the canonical tool for simple traffic control.  Beyond that (more complicated uses), I haven't found anything easier than just reading the docs and writing my own scripts.

Answer (score -1):

There are some linux-based traffic shaping appliances (rackmounted boxes) around that have (older, less featureful) open source software available.  Sorry, I can't recall the product name just now.  But yes, there are nicer options than a simple script.