# What are the best open source tools for shaping office bandwidth usage?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

We have a 3 MB pipe whose background noise is usually around 1.5 - 2 MB/S. This tends to burst up to capacity when when someone heads over to ESPN stream a video.

It would be nice to be able to isolate those events and throttle the bandwidth of the offender or segment out a "standard" vs. "non-standard" traffic scheme and put non-white listed websites on the non-standard side.

Are there open source tools to allow our small business to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There were a few posts about this here: [Traffic Management recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/8961/traffic-management-recommendations)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [tcng](http://tcng.sourceforge.net/) with good results. Check this [QoS article @wikipedia too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service#Open_Source_QoS_Software). There's also [WonderShaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/).

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you asked, but you might want to investigate running a Squid proxy internally there. It will at least cut back the duplicated traffic of everyone going to CNN, etc

Answer (score 0):

Quite often this function can be handled by your router.  Even a simple home/gaming router like the D-Link DGL-4100 contains QoS functionality.  Other more "business" level products like Sonicwall are affordable and will do this as well.  I think you will find a hardware solution much more manageable than something open source in the long run and the cost is negligible.